# Add Bing Maps Application to worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, bing-maps

In Excel 2013 it is possible to insert a Bing Maps application into a WorkSheet (Insert > Apps > Bing Maps). Does anyone know how I can programmatically insert this application to an Excel sheet? I'm developing a C# Excel add-in in Visual Studio. It looks like it is an image or chart object but I've no idea how to implement it, and I've not been able to find much detail online either. There is some information on how to do this in earlier versions of Excel, but not in 2013 with this new Bing Maps application.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel object model doesn't provide anything for dealing with Office Apps unfortunately. I.e. you can't install the application (Office App) programmatically.